# How to make a simple but scalable private message system (nosql)?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm building a simple private messages system for a large nosql website and I'm thinking about the table design. Number of reads is probably equal to (or twice) the number of writes, but reads will need all (recent) messages.

- My first thought was to make a table `threads` (columns: threadId, user1, user2), and table `messages` (columns: messageId, threadId, messageText). However, some simulations show that the `messages` index won't fit into RAM.
- My next thought was to make just a single table `threads` (columns: user1, user2, contents) and update the column `contents` every time someone replies in the conversation (using `$push` on an array). That's slower than insert, especially since the length of that text field grows at every reply.

Is my second thought the proper way to deal with this situation? Or is there a more efficient way to append small texts to large texts? I'm currently using mongodb but willing to change if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use combination of both ways? mostly u need to read **recent** messages and do **not** need the rest!

So i would suggest to create all these 3 tables (e.g `recent`, `threads`, `messages` which recent is based on your second approach)!

Recent keep 20 most recent messages in `recent`! and if you've more than 20 messages delete old ones from `recent` and put them into `threads` and `messages`.

For migration I would suggest you to do it in a bulk operation. e.g create a script on mongo and run it every hour.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Based on that suggestion I think I'll use the following variation: a table `recent_posts` to be used as in method 1, a table `threads` for use as in method 2, and every 24 hours (at night) I clear the recent_posts and append them to the accumulation fields in the treads table.